# ibtoold CompileStoryboard error: Controller cannot be nil

Tags: xcode, storyboard, cocoa-bindings, ibtool

On build XCode is freezing, and post the log message:

```
ibtoold[846:179360] Ignoring exception related to working with bindings: NSInvalidArgumentException, Controller cannot be nil
```

ibtoold process takes 98% CPU.

I understand that i have an error in bindings. How can i find the error in storyboard, or get more info?

XCode 7.1.1
OS X El Capitan 10.11

Comment: Have you looked at the xml source for the storyboard?

Comment: How is the `Controller` referenced in the storyboard?  Does it exist as an object?

Comment: 1. xml source doesn't show anything interesting. XCode doesn't show any reference on error in storyboard, but the code seems to be ok. 2. "Controller" does not not exist as an object - there are only NSViewController, NSWindowController, NSArrayController as a class, but there is no object. And it is not referenced in storyboard.

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1: Same problem, no idea how to find the error. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you use view-based NSTableView, and you bind your cells to NSArrayController, *NSArrayController should have value for "Content Set"*.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today. I am still no clearer on bindings and why ibtoold is raising the exception. But searching through the xml, I found the binding that was causing the problem and got the storyboard compiling again. The xml was:

```
<connections>
    <binding destination="fXn-uG-csF" name="value" keyPath="objectValue" id="4ZS-gg-XUq"/>
</connections>
```

From this I found the object that had the binding. It was the cell version of a text field as a subview of the text field. I had removed the binding to the text field in Xcode, but the cell still had it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all binding statements and then had a clean compile. Thereafter I re-added step by step the bindings. The error occurred when adding a maybe erroneous  binding to a table view cell [image: Table view cell with wrong binding]